# Почему eslint ругается, как будто синтаксическая ошибка но код выполняется верно

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

Почему eslint ругается, как будто синтаксическая ошибка но код выполняется верно. Выполняю и работаю в системе с 11 нодой. При этом никакой правило не нарушено, то есть редактор не предлагает ссылку на доку.

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token *eslint

let GeneratorGetCatalogUrl = async function*() {
    let numPage = 1
    let { maxNumberCatPage = 10 } = config
    while (--maxNumberCatPage) {
      yield await getCatalogUrlByPage(numPage)
      numPage++
    }
  }
```

конфиг еслинта

```
{
  "extends": ["standard", "prettier", "prettier/standard"],
  "plugins": ["import", "prettier", "standard"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2017,
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  },
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "off",
    "space-before-function-paren": 0,
    "new-cap": 0,
    "prettier/prettier": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: в еслинте может быть настройка на старый стандрат где еще не было генераторов

Comment: да спс добавил конфиг

Comment: похоже проблема именно в связке async + generator. Если убрать одну из частей - проверка проходит. также можно попробовать поменять `"ecmaVersion": 2017,` на 2018